# Oracle sql query not showing specific date

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my first time with oracle database. So I save data with date 30/04/20 and I want to retrieve it. So I use `SELECT * FROM USER_ACTION WHERE ACTION_DATE_TIME <= '30-APR-20'  order by ACTION_DATE_TIME desc` but no data with date 30/04/20 are shown. However when I use  `SELECT * FROM USER_ACTION WHERE ACTION_DATE_TIME <= '01-MAY-20'  order by ACTION_DATE_TIME desc`, I can see the data. Is there anyway that I can get date with exact date? no need to put extra +1 day to get it.

This is result when use `30-APR-20`:

[image: Query result]

This is result when use `01-MAY-20`:

[image: Query result 2]

Comment: A few observations. 1) you insist you don't want to change the data, but no one is suggesting changing the data. The suggestion is to change your query to match the reality of the data. 2) " WHERE ACTION_DATE_TIME <= '30-APR-20'" .  Assuming ACTION_DAT_TIME is, as it should be, a DATE or a TIMESTAMP, you are comparing that against a string, forcing orcle to an implied TO_DATE. This will bite you. Better to explicity include the proper to_date() yourself. 3) 2-digit years.  You are repeating the mistakes that caused Y2k.  Always, always use 4-digit years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your `ACTION_DATE_TIME` column be a datetime, with time component, if you want to include 30th April 2020 proper, you should be using this inequality:

```
SELECT *
FROM USER_ACTION
WHERE ACTION_DATE_TIME < date '2020-05-01'
ORDER BY ACTION_DATE_TIME DESC;
```

This will include all dates strictly *less* than 1st May 2020, which include all of 30th April 2020.

If the date value is coming from the outside, then just add one day to it:

```
SELECT *
FROM USER_ACTION
WHERE ACTION_DATE_TIME < date '2020-05-01' + 1
ORDER BY ACTION_DATE_TIME DESC;
```

Comment: the date actually is user input data, so it is not ideal to change it. so I just try to use what I get directly. your answer is suggesting me to add an extra day for everytime time user submit a date

Comment: The answer I have given you is best practice when searching for datetime ranges limited to certain ending day.

Comment: Ok noted that. Thanks for info. But still, I prefer not to change the user input data

Comment: Adding one day to a date is simple, and just requires doing `+ 1`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you a lot. Did not know can just add +1 directly to query.

Answer (score 1):

use `trunc` to convert date time to date as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_ACTION 
WHERE TRUNC(ACTION_DATE_TIME) <= '30-APR-20'  
order by ACTION_DATE_TIME desc
```

Comment: Can you explain what ```TRUNC``` does?

Comment: Note that this option leaves the `WHERE` clause not sargable, meaning any index on `ACTION_DATE_TIME` cannot be used.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I had no idea about it, Thanks.

Comment: @zealous Your answer is completely valid, and is another way to handle the OP's use case.  But, in terms of performance, it's always best to leave the possibility of using an index.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen unless there's an index on trunc(action_date_time) or the table is partitioned.
still, your point is abosolutely valid